# read text file then get content and show to table yii2

Tags: javascript, json, yii2

This is my `javascript` below my form:

```
$('#idOfButton').click(function(){
var id = $('#input').val(); 
    $.get('index.php?r=tbltime/get-file',{ id : id },function(data){
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

This is my `controller` for my view:

```
public function actionGetFile($id)
{
    $id = file_get_contents($id);
    echo Json::encode($id);

}
```

My `table` in my form view:

```
<table id="sampleTbl", class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr id="myRow">
            <th>BIB</th>
            <th>Time Start</th>
            <th>Time End</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

My `text file`:

```
202#00:00:00.000000#00:02:13.045000
764#00:03:12.037300#00:04:12.123000
223#00:04:50.011000#00:05:12.045000
```

What i want is to get content when i browse my text file then show in to table?? when i try use alert to show my content file its's not work. Anybody help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `file_get_contents` obviously can't read your file, because your file is not available in `C:\fakepath\dataimport.txt`. If you want to read your file on the disk `D:/` then you have to provide full path to your file's directory `file_get_contents('FULL PATH TO THE FILE DIRECTORY'.$id)` . Please note that this approach is not good because you are hardcoding the values in your script. If you move this code from your local machine to the server, it might happen that something will not work.

If you want to read your file from the disk `C:\` then copy file from disk D:\ to `C:\fakepath\dataimport.txt`.

In your controller after the line  echo `Json::encode($id);` put line `Yii::app()->end();` because you don't want to render any view file in this action.

**Update**

There are three possible scenarios.

**First scenario**
First scenario is when a file you want to display in the table is file that you are aware of, meaning this is not file uploaded by your customer. In that case, copy and paste your file into your project folder and just provide relative path to it, and function will be able to read. This will always work, even when you deploy your project to other server.

**Second scenario**
Other scenario is that file will come from the end user. In that case, you have to first upload a file using PHP, and then send file content to your Ajax script.

**Third scenario**
Use JavaScript to read content of the file and display it in the view. Here is one example: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-Parse-and-display-CSV-Text-file-using-JavaScript-jQuery-and-HTML5.aspx

Comment: how to get full path when i use form like this `<label class="control-label">Select File</label> <input id="input" type="file" class="file"></input>` ???

Comment: thank you for link in third scenario its so help me! @mrD

Answer (score 0):

What happened when your alert shows? What is response code of ajax get request? If there are errors please paste them here.

EDIT: 
Probably, in your input, from where you get your file name, only file name is present, not full path to file. So you should modify your action by adding path prefix to `file_get_contents` method:

```
public function actionGetFile($id)
{
    $fileContent= file_get_contents('D:/'.$id);
    echo Json::encode($fileContent);
    Yii::app()->end();

}
```

Comment: eror for reponse `<pre>PHP Warning &#039;yii\base\ErrorException&#039; with message &#039;file_get_contents(C:\fakepath\dataimport.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory&#039;` my file in drive D:dataimport.txt but this error get drive C. i don't know about it